# How can I change value from a node when having a server instance (node-opcua)

Tags: opc-ua, node-opcua

I'm using node-opcua library. I have instance of OPCUAServer. How can I get node value and edit it?

I assume OPC client should be able to do it, but I want to interact with OPC server since I'm responding to an internal event.

Should I maybe use something like [WriteRequest](http://node-opcua.github.io/api_doc/0.2.0/files/packages_node-opcua-service-write__generated___auto_generated_WriteRequest.js.html) to perform such operation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

alternatively you can use the `setValueFromSource` method on the variable.
This will bypass all Read/Write access checking that takes place in writeValue.
It is also synchronous

```
nodeToChange.setValueFromSource({ dataType: "Double", value: 3.14});
```

`setValueFromSource` can take an optional statusCode

```
nodeToChange.setValueFromSource(
     { dataType: "Double", value: 3.14}, 
     opcua.StatusCodes.BadWaitingForInitialData
);
```

if not specified StatusCodes.Good is assumed.

and a optional source timestamp

```
nodeToChange.setValueFromSource(
    { dataType: "Double", value: 3.14},
     opcua.StatusCodes.Good, new Date());
```

Answer (score 1):

I manage to resolve it with UAVariable's writeValue() method:

```
var opcua = require('node-opcua');

var server = new opcua.OPCUAServer({
  port: OpcServerConfig.port, 
  resourcePath: OpcServerConfig.resourcePath, 
  buildInfo: OpcServerConfig.buildInfo
});

var nodeToChange = server.engine.addressSpace.findNode('ns=1;b=1020FFAA');

nodeToChange.writeValue(
      null, 
      new opcua.DataValue({
        value: new opcua.Variant({dataType: opcua.DataType.Double, value: 5})
      }),
      null, 
      () => { }
);
```